# Erro ao tentar imprimir documento: O servidor RPC não está disponível

Tags: c#, pdf, impressora

Fiz um software onde uma das páginas pode ser impressa. Em alguns computadores ele funciona normalmente e imprime a página em PDF sem problemas. Em outras, ao tentar imprimir, surge o erro: "O servidor RPC não está disponível."

Tentei reiniciar o serviço do RPC na máquina onde ocorreu o erro, ms não deu certo.

O que mais posso tentar para resolver isso?

Obs.: Meu programa já tem o System.Drawing.Printing;

Segue o trecho do código que gera a impressão:

```
    private void imprimirToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create new PrintDocument 
        System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pd = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
        // Add a PrintPageEventHandler for the document 
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
        // Print the document 
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        pd.Print();

    }

    private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
        // Create and initialize print font 
        System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10);
        // Create Rectangle structure, used to set the position of the chart Rectangle 
        Rectangle myRec = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(10, 30, 1120, 750);
        // Draw a line of text, followed by the chart, and then another line of text 
        //ev.Graphics.DrawString("Relatório", printFont, Brushes.Black, 500, 500);
        chartMain.Printing.PrintPaint(ev.Graphics, myRec);
        //ev.Graphics.DrawString("Line after chart", printFont, Brushes.Black, 500, 500);
    }
```

Comment: Quando falha, o teste é feito em uma impressora remota?

Comment: Olá rray! Sim, é uma impressora remota. Descobri que isso estava acontecendo pelo fato desta impressora remota não estar mapeada na minha rede. Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Cria um resposta :) p ajudar outros com esse problema